# chrome mobile browse has additional space below body

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1XdM.jpg)

I'm facing two issues.

Basically [ONLY] chrome mobile browser has additional space below the body. It cause can scroll even tough I make body unscrollable. normal case(inccuding safari or any other browser) it works as I expected.

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

other issue could be related with that additional space below. After Keyboard disappear scroll position is located like uploaded picture.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `100dvh` (*Dynamic Viewport Height*) instead of `100vh` to `body` ?